# If someone gets my Routers Device Access code can they remove the firewall settings?

Tags: passwords, router

If this happens what can a bad person do to my firewall settings, will I be able to know if this happens. i.e. would my pc be wide open to malware as soon as I get on a browser like google?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** but the following has to be true:

- They are on your LAN, i.e connected to your network (Wifi, ethernet etc)
- They can get remote access to your network. E.g Many routers have a remote access protocol, make sure to disable it or if you really need it make sure to have a great password. Take steps to secure your router generally, (disable UPnP etc) to block all remote access points.
- You have a vulnerability in your router. This is very common, keep your firmware up to date, check online to see if your router has any un-patched issues.

Comment: Thank you, where is a good source for how to disable remote access and or UPnP, and is UPnP like Peer to Peer as in torrenting?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to any question like "if someone gets my [only credential to access something], can they [do what I can do with that something]?" is, in general, yes. If you can use the Devices Access Code to remove firewall settings, so could an attacker.

However, in general these codes are used as passwords for an administration panel which is typically local, for example at 192.168.1.1. In this case, it can't be accessed remotely unless they have already infected, or found a serious vulnerability, in your router or a device you're using.